# Certain functions do not work in ammo.js, despite BulletPhysics documentation showing they should

Tags: javascript, bulletphysics, ammo.js

To clarify - ammo.js is a port of Bullet Physics using emscripten

Ok, so I just made this quick and dirty script to move a block with keypresses, that is fine and working. However, when i want to rotate the block chrome keeps telling me that

> TypeError: quat1.setEulerZYX is not a function
>
> at drawScene

even though the [Bullet Documentation](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtQuaternion.html) clearly states that setEulerZYX is a function

```
try {
    var px = parseFloat(tempCamz); // Turns strings into integers
    var py = parseFloat((tempCamy * -1));
    var pz = parseFloat(tempCamx);
    var quat1 = new Ammo.btQuaternion();
    quat1.setEulerZYX(0.5,0,0);
    var blockShape = new Ammo.btBoxShape(new Ammo.btVector3(1/4, 1, 1/2));
    var mass = 1;
    var blockTransform = new Ammo.btTransform();
    blockTransform.setIdentity();
    blockTransform.setRotation(quat1);
    blockTransform.setOrigin(new Ammo.btVector3(px, py, pz));
    var localInertia = new Ammo.btVector3(0, 0, 0);
    var myMotionState = new Ammo.btDefaultMotionState(blockTransform);
    blockShape.calculateLocalInertia(mass,localInertia);
    var rbInfo = new Ammo.btRigidBodyConstructionInfo(mass, myMotionState, blockShape, localInertia);
    var body = new Ammo.btRigidBody(rbInfo);
    body.setLinearVelocity(origvel);

    instances[i].physObj = body;
    dynamicsWorld.addRigidBody(instances[i].physObj);

    } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ammo.js doesn't expose full API of all Bullet entities:

> Not all classes are exposed, as only what is described in ammo.idl is wrapped.

— From the [README](https://github.com/kripken/ammo.js#bindings-api)

See [ammo.idl](https://github.com/kripken/ammo.js/blob/master/ammo.idl#L37) for list of methods that are available.

You can update `ammo.idl` and add definitions for methods that you need and then use custom build or try to get your changes into upstreem, see [this issue](https://github.com/kripken/ammo.js/issues/60) for some instructions.

I was not patient enough to build this thing myself (mostly, because of issues with default emscripten package from Debian repository), but having emscripten working it should be easy enough to include declaration for `setEulerZYX()` in `btQuaternion` definition, which after update may look like this (but I didn't try, so it may or may not work):

```
interface btQuaternion {
  void btQuaternion(float x, float y, float z, float w);
  void setValue(float x, float y, float z, float w);
  void setEulerZYX(float yaw, float pitch, float roll);
};
btQuaternion implements btQuadWord;
```